# Is it possible to let this macro change a value in the same row as the Instr value is in?

Tags: vba, excel

I created a macro that looks for a partial string in my worksheet. If the string is found it changes a value to 0 in a different colon.

**Macro**

```
Sub Contain_Copy()
    Dim ranger                              As Long
    Dim lastrow                             As Long
    Dim FromSheet As Worksheet, ToSheet     As Worksheet
    Dim a                                   As Long

    Set FromSheet = Sheets("C")
    Set ToSheet = Sheets("D")
    lastrow = FromSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

    For ranger = 2 To lastrow
        If InStr(1, FromSheet.Cells(ranger, "N"), "ET7", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            a = a + 1
            Worksheets("C").Cells(a, 3) = 0
        End If
    Next ranger
End Sub
```

In this instance a string in my worksheet "E3A02ET7" is in column "N" and row 9. 
Since it contains "ET7", a value in column "C" will be changed into 0.

The problem is that it changes the value in row 1.

I want it to change the value in row 9, since this is the same row as the value with the partial string ET7.

Could you help me with finding a solution to this?

Much obliged,
B. van Starkenburg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to change `FromSheet.Cells(a, 3) = 0` to `FromSheet.Cells(ranger, 3) = 0`

So your code becomes:

```
Sub Contain_Copy()
    Dim ranger                              As Long
    Dim lastrow                             As Long
    Dim FromSheet As Worksheet, ToSheet     As Worksheet

    Set FromSheet = Sheets("C")
    lastrow = FromSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

    For ranger = 2 To lastrow
        If InStr(1, FromSheet.Cells(ranger, "N"), "ET7", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            FromSheet.Cells(ranger, 3) = 0
        End If
    Next ranger
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, so defining "a" wasn't even necessary?

Comment: @BerendStarkenburg - Right, `a` was not required.

Answer (score 0):

The code would be like this.

```
Sub Contain_Copy()
Dim ranger                              As Long
Dim lastrow                             As Long
Dim FromSheet As Worksheet, ToSheet     As Worksheet
Dim a                                   As Long

Set FromSheet = Sheets("C")
Set ToSheet = Sheets("D")
lastrow = FromSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
With FromSheet
    For ranger = 2 To lastrow
        If InStr(.Cells(ranger, "N"), "ET7") Then
            .Cells(ranger, 3) = 0
        End If
    Next ranger
End With
End Sub
```